# jQuery Validation Engine and RadComboBox

Tags: telerik, jquery-validation-engine, radcombobox

I am using the jQuery Validation Engine with the Telerik`s RadComboBox and it is not working. Works perfect with asp:TextBox. Did someone use the engine with RadComboBox?

[MyRadComboBox](http://www.telerik.com/account/ClientsFiles/209670a1-e491-4465-b62f-760052d57945_MyRadComboBox.png?accesskey=36515E98E54844B4990E43DAD108BA63192D2894&expires=635383926751814996)

[WebMethod](http://www.telerik.com/account/ClientsFiles/56fb0c60-807e-448c-a2c4-f545cc398ad7_WebMethod.png?accesskey=F20397DCB75BEBB561C6B15E2CFEB0A7C3B581D4&expires=635383926751814996)

Comment: Please add sample code of what you have tried

Comment: Sorry about not showing. And here is the JS - http://pastebin.com/4gsTZ5A8

Comment: add code here pls,do we need to register telerik first to answer question?